# Explain this behavior of format() in R

Tags: r, format

```
> format(1111111, digits=10, nsmall=2, decimal.mark=".", big.mark=",")
[1] "1,111,111.00"
```

As expected. However:

```
> format(1000000, digits=10, nsmall=2, decimal.mark=".", big.mark=",")
[1] "1e+06"
```

Expected: `10,000,000.00`. I looked up `?format`, nothing obvious there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `scientific` parameter:

```
format(1000000, digits=10, nsmall=2, decimal.mark=".", 
       big.mark=",",scientific=FALSE)
[1] "1,000,000.00"
```